# Unable to install Certificate Enrolment Policy Web Service

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, certificate, certificate-authority

I'm running on Windows 2k8 Enterprise edition, and when adding the Active Directory Certificate Services, I don't see the option to add the Certificate Enrolment Policy Web service in the dialog box.

[image]

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for this problem that I've seen is that the target server does not meet the [prerequisites for installing the Certificate Enrollment Policy Web service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759214.aspx), specifically the domain membership.

---

### Installation requirements

Before installing the certificate enrollment Web services, ensure that your environment meets these requirements:

- A host computer as a domain member running Windows Server 2008 R2.
- An Active Directory forest with a Windows Server 2008 R2 schema. See Prepare a Windows 2000 or Windows Server 2003 Forest Schema for a Domain Controller That Runs Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2 (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=93242).
- An enterprise certification authority (CA) running Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, or Windows Server 2003.

  - If the Certificate Enrollment Web Service is configured for client certificate authentication, the CA must be running Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows Server 2008.
  - For enrollment across forests, the CA must be installed on a computer running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise or Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter. See Configuring Certificate Enrollment Web Services for Enrollment Across Forest Boundaries.
- Client computers running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.
- A Server Authentication certificate installed for HTTPS.

---